# C++ Pointers in Typedefs

Tags: c++, pointers, typedef

I'm relatively new to C++, I start by reading [C++ Primer 4th edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201721481). It has a section explains about Pointers and Typedefs, start with bellowing code.

```
typedef string *pstring;
const pstring cstr;
```

<del>I know that after I define `typedef string *pstring;` I can use `*pstring` to declare string variable in my code.</del>

`*pstring value1; // both of these line are identical,

string value2;   // value 1 and value2 are string`

The book continue with `const pstring cstr1;` and `*const string cstr2;` are identical. I don't understand why they're same declaration?

Comment: *"I can use *pstring to declare string variable in my code."* -- Um.  No you can't.  And `*const string cstr2;` is not valid.  What page are you on?

Comment: If you are serious about C++, you should get a copy of *[Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html)*.

Comment: @ObscureRobot: Sure, but C++ Primer is a fine book as well.  And I'm pretty sure it doesn't say what he says it says.

Comment: `const pstring cstr1` defines a pointer to a const string named cstr1.  `*const string cstr2` is invalid, but if you meant `const string * cstr2` you've defined a pointer to a const string named cstr2.

Comment: @Michael: `const pstring cstr1` declares a const pointer to string, not a pointer to const string.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I just update my question, it's my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Anonymous: You deleted that one erroneous statement.  You still have 2 invalid declarations(`*pstring value1;` and `*const string cstr2;`), 2 erroneous comments(*"// both of these line are identical,"* and *"// value 1 and value2 are string"*), and 1 erroneous statement(*"const pstring cstr1; and *const string cstr2; are identical"*, and after you fix all that, I have no idea what your question is anymore.

Comment: `const pstring cstr1;` and `*const string cstr2;` are identical" is in page 130, is it incorrect?

Comment: does `typedef string *pstring;` mean pstring = string pointer variable, right?

Comment: My version of C++ Primer does not say *"const pstring cstr1; and *const string cstr2; are identical"*, it says, in a line of code "string * const cstr; // equivalent to const pstring cstr".  This is correct, and completely different from what you are saying. --  *"does typedef string *pstring; mean pstring = string pointer variable, right?"* -- Right.  Although, I always prefer to say "pointer to string" instead of "string pointer".  That way we're perfectly clear at what's getting pointed at.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Do you mean `*const string cstr2` and `string * const cstr;` are difference?

Comment: @Anonymous I've answered your question in chat. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4455/discussion-between-anonymous-and-benjamin-lindley

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You are correct. This is an excellent example where typedefs are indeed very different than macros.  This is also the reason that I hate typedef'ing raw pointer types, and since I never do this in my code, I of course answered without thinking.  Thanks for the correction.  I've deleted my comment (since it wouldn't let me edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not identical.

```
 pstring v1;  // declares a pointer to string
 string v2;  // declares an object of type string
 string* v3;  // this is the same type as v1
```

Comment: Why I can't use `typedef *string pstring;` then declare `pstring value2`? (I get compile time eror?)

Comment: @Anonymous: Because `*string` is not a type, therefore you cannot make a typedef of it.  `string` is a type, and `string*` is a type, but not `*string`.

Answer (score 2):

I really hope the book you're quoting isn't as inaccurate as your quotations make it seem.  I feel sure that you haven't quoted it accurately.  Please go back and compare what's in the book (I don't have a copy) to what you've written.

Given:

```
typedef string *pstring;
```

You write that

```
const pstring cstr1;
```

and

```
*const string cstr2;
```

are identical.  In fact, both are invalid.

If you declare something `const`, you need to provide an initial value for it.  And the syntax of `*const string cstr2;` is just wrong.

So here's a correct way to do it:

```
typedef string *pstring;
const pstring cstr1 = 0;  // initialize to 0, a null pointer
string *const cstr2 = 0;  // the same
```

Both `cstr1` and `cstr2` are const (i.e., read-only) pointers to string.

Note that the `const` keyword has to be *after* the `*`, because we want a const pointer to string, not a pointer to const string.

But in any case, declaring a typedef for a pointer type is usually a bad idea.  The fact that a type is a pointer type affects almost everything you do with it; making a typedef for it hides that fact.

Comment: Does `string *const cstr2 = 0;` identical to `*const string cstr = 0;`? If not, why?

Comment: @Anonymous: What?  No, I just said that `*const string cstr = 0;` is a syntax error.

Comment: @KeithThompson Actually, `const pstring cstr1;` might not be a syntax error; it depends on context.  If it is in a function body or at global scope, then it is an error.  If it is in a class declaration, it is valid, but must be initialized in the constructor initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

It's great that you are learning about typedefs, but personally when you see ten thousand of them in your application with millions of lines of code, then.... typedefs lose their luster. They then only serve to obsfucate the real code. I swear some devs whose code I've maintained drank the typedef cool aid and use them for everything!

The only benefit I've seen is to use them to shorten very long typed names. such as long types used with the STL.